# Adding metadata data to S3 object using S3 outbound gateway

Tags: spring, spring-boot, amazon-s3, spring-integration, spring-integration-aws

have written code for spring integration aws application, which currently  upload files from source folder to target S3 bucket using s3-outbound-gateway. Would like to add below user defined metadata and their value about the file while uploading the file in S3 bucket.

x-amz-meta-sourcePath : /test

x-amz-meta-targetPath :/targetbucket/

x-amz-meta-timestamp  : (#timestamp value)

Would like to know how to add metadata using S3 outbound gateway or other way. Any documentation/example/suggestion will be helpful to achieve this.

```
<util:map id="userMetadata" value-type="java.lang.String">
            <entry key="x-amz-meta-source" value="testsource" />
            <entry key="x-amz-meta-sourcePath" value="testpath" />    
            <entry key="x-amz-meta-targetPath" value="headers.TARGET_PATH" />               </util:map>

        <bean id="objectMetadata"  class="com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata">
        <property name="userMetadata" ref="userMetadata"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="uploadMetadataProvider"  class="org.springframework.integration.aws.outbound.S3MessageHandler$UploadMetadataProvider">
        <property name="objectMetadata" ref="objectMetadata"/>
        </bean>
<int-aws:s3-outbound-gateway id="s3File"
        request-channel="filesS3GateWay"
        reply-channel="filesS3ChainChannel"
        transfer-manager="transferManager"
        bucket-expression = "headers.TARGET_PATH"
        key-expression="headers.file_name"
        upload-metadata-provider="uploadMetadataProvider"
        command="UPLOAD">
        <int-aws:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <ref bean="retryAdvice" />
        </int-aws:request-handler-advice-chain>
    </int-aws:s3-outbound-gateway>
```

Comment: What is that metadata? Where does it go in AWS? Is it a part of HTTP request? Or are they really have to be added to the `S3Object`? Maybe an `upload-metadata-provider` is answer for you?

Comment: metadata have to be added along with S3object(file) during uploading the file in bucket. Metadata will go to S3object metadata (key-value pair) defined in properties tab of aws .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is this:

```
    <xsd:attribute name="upload-metadata-provider">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                Reference to an instance of
                'org.springframework.integration.aws.outbound.S3MessageHandler$UploadMetadataProvider'.
            </xsd:documentation>
            <xsd:appinfo>
                <tool:annotation kind="ref">
                    <tool:expected-type
                            type="org.springframework.integration.aws.outbound.S3MessageHandler$UploadMetadataProvider"/>
                </tool:annotation>
            </xsd:appinfo>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
```

So, you inject such a `UploadMetadataProvider`:

```
/**
 * The callback to populate an {@link ObjectMetadata} for upload operation.
 * The message can be used as a metadata source.
 */
public interface UploadMetadataProvider {

    void populateMetadata(ObjectMetadata metadata, Message<?> message);

}
```

And populate into that `ObjectMetadata` whatever you need based on the request message if that.

Comment: Getting below exception Failed to convert property value of type 'com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata' to required type 'org.springframework.integration.aws.outbound.S3MessageHandler$UploadMetadataProvider' for property 'uploadMetadataProvider'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata' to required type 'org.springframework.integration.aws.outbound.S3MessageHandler$UploadMetadataProvider' for property 'uploadMetadataProvider': no matching editors or conversion strategy found.

Comment: Huh? It has to be a `S3MessageHandler$UploadMetadataProvider` implementation. Why do you just use that plain `com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata`? That's not a contract of that `upload-metadata-provider` property.

Comment: oops.. yes its an interface inside S3MessageHandler... edited the code above... can you advise how to pass the metadata to upload-metadata-provider property

Comment: Huh? You don't need to do that. The `populateMetadata(ObjectMetadata metadata, Message<?> message)` provides that for you for modification. If you have one, you can just copy/paste its content into the provided in that method implementation.